# write multiple list in file as columns

Tags: python

I have three lists

```
list1 = ['123','124','125']
list2 = [0.223333, 0.3434344, 0.4545454]
list3 = [ 0.53434, 0.453535, 0.534343]
```

`list1` is list of `str`; `list2` and `list3` are `float64`.
I want to print them in a file like

```
123 0.223333 0.53434
124 0.343434 0.453535
125 0.454545 0.534343
```

I tried

```
writer = csv.writer(writeCSVfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quotechar='"')
row_list = zip(list1, str(list2), str(list3))
for row in row_list: 
    writer.writerows(row)
```

But I getting digits printed out in weird manner.

Comment: can you elaborate on what the ordering problem is?

Comment: Are you opposed to `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: `zip(list1, list2, list3)` because `csv.Writer` can handle numbers and strings and change `writer.writerows(row)` to `writer.writerow(row)`.  OR `writer.writerows(zip(list1, list2, list3))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make a string out of the other two lists. That turns them into an iterator over the *characters in the string* rather than the elements in the list.

Try this instead: `row_list = zip(list1, list2, list3)`

Oh, and if you're only writing one row, use `writerow` instead of `writerows`

Comment: And there's always the option of shortening it to `writer.writerows(zip(list1, list2, list3))`.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is well suited for this.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['123','124','125']
list2 = [0.223333, 0.3434344, 0.4545454]
list3 = [ 0.53434, 0.453535, 0.534343]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': list1, 'l2': list2, 'l3': list3})
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```